# How to check CUDA Compute Capability?

Tags: graphics-card, gpu, cuda

I just playaround with open-source software called Meshroom.
https://github.com/alicevision/meshroom

One of it's processes called DepthMap gives an error:
*This program needs a CUDA-Enabled GPU (with at least compute capability 2.0).*

On wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUDA) I read that my video card: GeForce GT 650M has the compute capablility 3.0.

Can I check the CUDA Compute Capability?

Is there something I missed? Or it should be bug in the Meshroom software?

Comment: Perhaps you need to install the [CUDA libraries](https://developer.nvidia.com/gpu-accelerated-libraries)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[GPU-z](https://www.techpowerup.com/gpuz/) will tell you everything about your card.

Under the Advanced tab is a dropdown for CUDA which will tell you exactly what your card supports:

[image]

It does *sound* like a bug though, the [Geforce 600 series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GeForce_600_series#Architecture) Wikipedia page also states CUDA 3.0 support.

Answer (score 3):

Try `deviceQuery executable` in `C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\vX.Y\extras\demo_suite`, following a [hint at the NVIDIA developer forum](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/what-is-the-compute-capability-of-a-geforce-gt-710/146956/4):

```
> Detected 1 CUDA Capable device(s)
> 
> Device 0: "**GeForce GT 710**"
>   CUDA Driver Version / Runtime Version          11.0 / 11.0
>   CUDA Capability Major/Minor version number:    3.5
>   Total amount of global memory:                 2048 MBytes (2147483648 bytes)
>   ( 1) Multiprocessors, (192) CUDA Cores/MP:     192 CUDA Cores
```

Thus, my CUDA Compute Capability is 3.5.

Answer (score 0):

Your card (GeForce GT 650M) has cuda capability 3.0.

This is the official page which lists all modern cards and their CUDA capability numbers: https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus